# Selenoid Error response from daemon: client is newer than server

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenoid

Getting an error when trying to start Selenoid with `cm` command:

```
$ ./cm selenoid start —vnc
2017/10/26 13:19:57 Using Docker...
2017/10/26 13:19:57 registry.ping url=https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/
2017/10/26 13:19:59 Failed to list images: Error response from daemon: client is newer than server (client API version: 1.29, server API version: 1.24)
2017/10/26 13:19:59 Downloading Selenoid...
2017/10/26 13:19:59 Fetching tags for image "aerokube/selenoid"...
2017/10/26 13:19:59 registry.tags url=https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/aerokube/selenoid/tags/list repository=aerokube/selenoid
2017/10/26 13:20:00 Failed to pull image "aerokube/selenoid:1.3.8": Error response from daemon: client is newer than server (client API version: 1.29, server API version: 1.24)
2017/10/26 13:20:00 Failed to start: failed to pull Selenoid image
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of incompatible version of the Docker client used inside `cm` and installed Docker server. `cm` internally is using just the same official Go client as `docker` command, so any environment variables are applicable. To fix this we need to tell the client to use correct Docker API version by setting an environment variable:

```
DOCKER_API_VERSION=1.24 ./cm selenoid start --vnc
```

**UPD:** starting from CM release 1.4.0 this is determined automatically.